How to type Indian Rupee Symbol directly in Excel VBA to Format Cells in Accounting Format?
Let's suppose, I have a range from "A1" to "A10". I want to automate applying accounting number format on these cells but with Indian Rupee Symbol, not US Dollars. How can I do this in VBA? Whenever I record macro, instead of showing the Indian Rupee Symbol the VBA editor shows "?".
I want to automate applying accounting number format on these cells but with Indian Rupee Symbol, not US Dollars.

Try Range("A1:A10").NumberFormat = ChrW(8377) & " 0.00"

Pls try
Sub ApplyCurrFormat()
    Const CUR = "_-[$$]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Range("A1:A10").NumberFormatLocal = Replace(CUR, "$$", "$" & ChrW(8377))
End Sub

